# Background Image on Button Adds Margins

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, button

I have a contact form, and when you submit and everything goes okay, while you're waiting for the email to send, a little loading .gif appears in place of the button text.  However, when my Javascript adds the image, there is some extra padding:

From:
[image: Before]
To:
[image: After]

If you look closely, there is extra space between the button and the textbox.  While it doesn't seem like much here, it is very noticeable when you see it change in real time.  The button doesn't actually change height, and the .gif is set by using `background:#222 url('/somewhere/load.gif') no-repeat center center;`

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: Not enough information, edit your post to include code. This looks like a fairly easy candidate for a minimal standalone test case to me.

Answer (score 0):

Like John said, there isn't a whole lot of information to work with here.

However, if you add `background-size: contain;` to the id/class that contains your gif, that may work.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with what is happening, even though you may want a different visual effect.

I took both of your button images and superimposed them as follows:

[image: Submit buttons from original post]

I made one image 50% transparent to line up the edges.

In both cases, the buttons have the same height.

What is happening is that your GIF image is sized so that it matches about 90% of the height of the button.

In contrast, the text ("Send") because of the font size, does not.  You may be able to get the text to be taller by adjusting the font-size and line-height and padding, but you will need to experiment.

Alternatively, make the height of the GIF to match the font-size.

### Illustrative Example

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/FsNe2/

Consider two similar buttons:

```
<input class="ex1" type="submit" value="Send Ex 1">
<input class="ex2" type="submit" value="Send Ex 2">
```

with the following CSS:

```css
input.ex1 {
    background: red url('http://placehold.it/60x60') no-repeat center center;
    font-size: 60px;
}
input.ex2 {
    background: red url('http://placehold.it/60x42') no-repeat center center;
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

which, in Firefox on a Windows 7 PC, renders like the following image:

[image: Submit buttons from jsfiddle]

In Example 1, I created a background image 60x60 pixels and the font size is 60px.
In this case, the image appears taller than the lettering because the font naturally leaves some space above and below the letters to account for ascenders and descenders.

In Example 2, I reduced the height of the image to 42px and this more closely matches the height of a uppercase E or S.

There is nothing wrong with you mark-up, just take into account these typographical details when creating your design elements.